# How to put a function taking an object of a template class as a parameter?

Tags: c++, templates, function, parameters

How do I go about writing a function which takes an object of a template class as a parameter? Would the following work? And can it go in the .cpp file instead of a header? (I have only written templated classes before).

```
template<class T> class LtdArray {
//class definition
}


template<class T> class LtdArray
bool ifBlockProcess(LtdArray &ltdarr, string strToProc) {
//add element to LtdArray
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When making [function templates](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_%28C%2B%2B%29#Function_templates), you don't need to include the class.  Your prototype should look like this:

```
template<class T>
bool ifBlockProcess(LtdArray<T> &ltdarr, string strToProc);
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should do the trick:

```
template<class T>
bool ifBlockProcess(LtdArray<T> & ltdarr, string strToProc)
{
    //add element to LtdArray
}
```

Comment: Yep, works as well as could be expected. Bad original pattern on my part now been replaced with specialisation anyway. Thanks.